# Почему отклонён флаг "слишком слабо обоснованный" на заведомо ложном комментарии?

Tags: поддержка, тревоги

К вопросу типа *"как сделать ..., используя X язык/ПО"* был оставлен комментарий по смыслу *"язык/ПО Y в 10 раз лучше"*, где X, Y языки/ПО достаточно близки (относительно других языков/ПО) для каких-то людей/задач один язык/ПО может быть более предпочтительным, для других другой язык/ПО -- о разнице на *целый порядок величины* не может быть и речи.

Суть в том, что достаточно только самого поверхностного знания о X, Y, чтобы понять что комментарий не соответствует действительности или *как минимум*  "слишком слабо обоснованный".

Вопрос к модераторам. Какая может быть возможная причина, что "слишком слабо обоснованный" флаг был отклонён? Может эта фраза что-то специальное означает (неудачный перевод) и этот флаг не следует для слабо обоснованных технических комментариев использовать?

Comment: Не уверен насчет конкретного флага (вроде бы не попадалось в последнее время ничего похожего по смыслу), но я обычно отклоняю флаги на "технически" необоснованных комментариях.

Comment: На enSO этот флаг внезапно называется too chatty, а в [русской справке по флагам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/flagging) - "чат - все, что не относится к вопросу или ответу"

Comment: @PashaPash: флаг я оставил, потому что человек на вопросе про язык/ПО X оставил комментарий по смыслу: "бросайте X, т.к. Y на порядок лучше" -- и на попытки скорректировать технически неточное утверждение, достаточно грубо отвечал/обзывался (предыдущие комментарии удалены сейчас).  Правильно ли я понял, что этот флаг не следует использовать на технически "слишком слабо обоснованных" комментариях? Можете ли вы рекомендации написать когда этот флаг следует/не следует использовать? Вообще его никогда не следует использовать?

Comment: "бросайте X, т.к. Y на порядок лучше" - на такое стоит ставить флаг "неконструктивный". Неконструктивные комментарии отслеживаются примерно так же, как нецензурные - модераторы получают дополнительное уведомление после определенного количества нецензурных или неконструктивных комментариев от одного пользователя - и, чаще всего, принимают меры.

Comment: Насчет "слишком слабо обоснованных" комментариев - этот флаг точно не стоит использовать на технически необоснованных комментариях - модераторы не могут быть компетентны во всем. Судя по всему, этот флаг - артефакт времен первоначального перевода ruSO. Стоит подождать Nicolas Chabanovsky и узнать у него, откуда вообще взялся этот вид тревоги.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Тревогу «слишком слабо обоснованный» к комментариям следует использовать в случаях:

- когда вы видите, что комментарий вообще не относится к вопросу;
- выражает субъективную позицию автора, которая никак не подтверждена доказательствами правоты.

В англоязычном сообществе для этого используется термин «too chatty» (много трепа, мало дела), который, в свою очередь, на сколько я понимаю, пошел от выражения «chit chatting» (болтовня). На странице [Тур](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) имеется следующее выражение:

> This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat.

[В русскоязычном сообществе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) эта фраза звучит как

> Этот сайт посвящён исключительно получению ответов. Это не форум для дискуссий. Здесь не место пустым разговорам.

Мы старались убрать из формулировки тревоги эмоциональный оттенок и определили «болтовню» как нечто, что не поддающееся проверке, так как основная цель этого сайта – сбор базы прикладных решений.

---

Тревога может быть отклонена по многим причин (в том числе, и случайно, по ошибке). Например, на сколько я помню, некоторые тревоги к комментариям  остается не обработанными (висят в очереди проверки), в случае удаления самого сообщения, но по факту комментарий может быть уже удален, (система может считать, что, теоретически, тревога сама по себе еще актуальна). Модератор вполне может отметить такую тревогу как «не требующую дальнейших действий» (то есть отклонить), так как видит, что все сообщение с комментариями уже удалено.

Comment: тревога «слишком слабо обоснованный» на [комментарии, который не относится к вопросу (кроме того, что упомянут язык по меткам вопроса) и выражает субъективную позицию автора (бездоказательно)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/651372/%d0%a3%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-selenium-webdriver-chromedriver-%d0%bd%d0%b0-linux-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%8f-python#comment1246489_651372) была отклонена (там если я правильно помню было много комментариев не по теме)