# Руководство по использованию тревог на комментариях

Tags: поддержка, комментарии, тревоги

На мете довольно подробно разобрано как следует голосовать за сообщения или отмечать тревогами вопросы или ответы. Однако тревоги комментариев объяснены ещё слишком слабо.

Если навести мышку на комментарий и нажать значок флажка, появится меню с выбором из пяти вариантов (в скобках варианты с enSO):

- нецензурный или оскорбительный (rude or offensive),
- неконструктивный (not constructive),
- устаревший (obsolete),
- слишком слабо обоснованный (too chatty),
- другое… (other…)

Если выбрать последний вариант, появится поле для ввода текста. Судя по всему, после отправки его прочитает модератор. А остальные флаги кто увидит?

Хотелось бы уяснить для себя, как правильно расставлять флаги тревог на комментариях? В каких случаях это стоит делать, когда какой пункт выбирать?

По поводу перевода. На английском SO, чтобы комментарий был отмечен первым вариантом тревоги, он даже не обязательно должен содержать нецензурную лексику. «Rude» — «грубый», «невежливый».

Я не очень разбираюсь в нюансах английского, но почему для варианта «устаревший» на enSO использовано «obsolete», а не какое-нибудь «outdated» или «deprecated»? В каком плане комментарий может быть устаревшим? (Кстати, тревога об устаревшем комментарии может устареть, и получится тавтология. На английском Stack Overflow для таких тревог использована фраза «aged away».)

«Too chatty» следует понимать как «слишком болтливый». Правда комментарий не может быть болтливым. В одном из своих [ответов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5173) Николай Чабановкий мимоходом определил, как нужно использовать эту тревогу. Хотелось бы получить аналогичные или даже более подробные разъяснения по оставшимся пунктам.

Какие конкретно реплики стоит отмечать флажком: все, которые предлагаются к удалению, или только одну? Очень хотелось бы увидеть примеры нежелательных комментариев и бесед под вопросами или ответами.

---

Перевод на [странице справки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/flagging) не согласован, а пояснения слишком коротки.

Есть ли возможность отметить комментарий как спам (или это не требуется)? Как отозвать тревогу с комментария?

**Обновление**

Недавно на StackOverflow обновился интерфейс тревог на комментариях:

> **Что не так с комментарием?**
>
> - Он выражает нетерпимость, связан с травлей или оскорбителен
>     (It contains harassment, bigotry, or abuse)
> - Он недружелюбен или враждебен (It's unfriendly or unkind)
> - Он больше не нужен (It's no longer needed)
> - Что-то ещё... (Something else...)

Comment: остальные флаги кто увидит - все флаги на комментариях уходят напрямую модераторам

Comment: Deprecated это только в области ИТ сравнялось с "устаревший". Более точный перевод это "от которого отказались", вовсе необязательно "старый" (но "былой"/"прошлый" -- вполне). Outdated необязательно означает неправильность, просто указывает на то что информация старая. Obsolete подходит лучше всего, как "неактуальный"/"неиспользуемый".

Comment: Устаревший - это когда информацию из комментария внесли в вопрос или ответ.

Comment: в тему: [Почему отклонён флаг "слишком слабо обоснованный" на заведомо ложном комментарии?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5171/23044)

Comment: "obsolete" я всегда понимал в буквальном смысле (хотя пример со  "слишком слабо обоснованный" категорией показывает, что буквальная интерпретация может не использоваться фактически): ответ исправили -> комментарий устарел.

Answer (score 2):

> По поводу перевода.

На RuSO установлен режим охлократии с элементами администраторской диктатуры. Если в переводе написано что-то странное, слабо относящееся к оригинальному тексту на английском, то это прямые последствия.

1. *нецензурный или оскорбительный (rude or offensive)* — всё, на что кто-то может оскорбиться
   пример: "ах ты ж редиска"
2. *неконструктивный (not constructive)* — всё, что уводит обсуждение от обсуждаемого вопроса
   пример: "слово 'что-то' пишется через дефис"
3. *устаревший (obsolete)* — всё, что может запутать или заставить встать на неверный путь будущих посетителей в силу изменения внешних условий
   пример: "magic quotes — это хорошо"
4. *слишком слабо обоснованный (too chatty)* — всё, что генерирует много текста при минимальной содержательности
   пример: "вот десять причин использовать табы для отступов"
5. *другое… (other…)* — всё, что не вписывается в пункты выше, а также требует действия от модератора, выходящие за рамки удаления одного сообщения
   пример: два юзера поцапались в диалоге на 50 сообщений, нужно принять меры

> Какие конкретно реплики стоит отмечать флажком: все, которые предлагаются к удалению, или только одну?

Одно, первое сообщение, по последнему варианту тревоги, с описанием ситуации.